# How to map domain to docker container?

Tags: docker, apache, redhat

I have a Redhat server. Here I installed docker and Apache for reverse Proxy. I ran multiple containers in it.

I would like to map domains to each container, So I setup a Reverse Proxy in Apache like this

For Example: http://example.com map to http://40.76.25.1:9999/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName       example.com
            ServerAlias      www.example.com.com

            LogLevel debug
            ProxyRequests off

            ProxyPreserveHost On

            #ProxyPass /public/static/ http://52.206.215.249/public/static/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
            #ProxyPassReverse /public/static/ http://52.206.215.249/public/static/
            ProxyPass / http://40.76.25.1:9999/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
            ProxyPassReverse / http://40.76.25.1:9999/   ##(Hostip Address)

            ErrorLog logs/1356.thapos.net_error_log
            TransferLog logs/1356.thapos.net_access_log

            SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive

</VirtualHost>
```

But This mapping was not working for me.
I don't know if this is the correct process or not. If this is not the right process let me know how we map domains for Docker Containers via Apache.

Comment: DNS A and AAAA records only give mappings for IP addresses, not TCP ports, so in addition to setting up hostname-based routing you also need to map your container to the standard HTTP(S) ports 80 and 443.

Comment: Did you configure the domain name server (DNS) that your browser is using?

Comment: Domain and mapping wise all settings are good. My problem is, How to map Domain to particular one container and where we need assign domain name in docker container settings.. am newbie to docker...